# Clicking HTML button with URL Parameters?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

Basically I am currently writing a Python Requests program and everything works fine so far, The issue is there is a button on the website that I want to be pressed. Currently the clicking stage is done in selenium which slows the process down completely.
Just like when filling in a form is there anyway to pass a parameter into a URL to click a button?
The button sends a POST command to a URL when clicked however when trying to recreate this in a browser or in python with .post the desired redirect does not happen.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simulate the click operation by sending the POST request?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't do anything for me when I try to use it, despite it being the one which google reports as being used when the button is clicked, I included the variable parameters and nothing happens, not in Python with .post or in Firefox when sending a post.

Comment: So your question is more in line of how to create a POST request in python - write what you tried

Comment: Basically I tried 

http://www.siteurl.com/shop/303359/add?utf8=%E2%9C%93&style=22037&size=46452&commit=add+to+basket
While on a lot of the sites pages including the product page and it wouldnt do anything, including when sending it as a post command